# Access a struct variable when struct is passed as a double pointer

Tags: c++, json, pointers, double-pointer

I have a function as follows

```
int check_inband_status(Port **ePort, Port **wPort, InbandPort *inbandPort)
{

                std::ifstream ring_config_file(RING_CONFIG_FILE);

                Json::Value ring_config;
                ring_config_file >> ring_config;
                (*ePort)->port_id = ring_config["east_port"]["port_id"].asInt();
                (*ePort)->port_type = ring_config["east_port"]["port_type"].asString();
                (*wPort)->port_id = ring_config["west_port"]["port_id"].asInt();
                (*ePort)->port_type = ring_config["west_port"]["port_type"].asString();

                ring_config_file.close();
}
```

I have a json file and I am reading it and assigning the values to ePort and wPort.
This is the variable ePort and wPort

```
class InbandPort : public Port
{
    public:
        uint32_t                vid;
        uint32_t                nicid;
        uint32_t                intf_id;
        uint32_t                number_of_nni;
        bool                    is_lag;
        olt_intf_type_t         intftype;
        Port                    *port1;
        Port                    *port2;
        SubportList             sPorts;
        ERPSPort                *erpsPort;
        bool                    is_active;
        bool                    is_dhcp_done; /* to mark the dhcp is done or not is static dhcp case by default value                                                   is true*/
        bool                    is_ring_configured;
        InbandPort() : Port()
        {
            vid             = INVALID_ID;
            nicid           = INVALID_ID;
            intf_id         = INVALID_ID;
            port1           = NULL;
            port2           = NULL;
            erpsPort        = NULL;
            is_lag          = false;
            is_dhcp_done    = false;
            is_ring_configured = false;
            port_id         = 0;
            number_of_nni   = 0;
        }
.....
```

Here is the json file

```
{
   "east_port" : {
      "port_id" : 2,
      "port_type" : "nni"
   },
   "west_port" : {
      "port_id" : 4,
      "port_type" : "nni"
   }
}
```

It is crashing at

```
(*ePort)->port_id = ring_config["east_port"]["port_id"].asInt();
```

I know I am making some mistake in accessing/assigning double pointer. Can someone please point me to it?

Edit: I am passing it as a double pointer because I want to access the same value from other function as well.
And how I am passing is

```
Port                       *ePort  = NULL;
Port                       *wPort = NULL;
check_inband_status(&ePort, &wPort, inbandPort);
```

Comment: Why does that function take double pointers at all? What are you passing to it? (From the prototype, I would expect that function to receive null pointers, then create `new` `Port`s and store pointers to them in `*ePort` and `*wPort`.)

Comment: You assign `(*ePort)->port_type` twice.  Maybe you should assign a value to `(*wPort)->port_type`?

Comment: The given sample cannot work. there is no element ```port_type''' in your class definition. Maybe in the base class? But then provide the complete class definition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the addresses of null pointers, so both `*ePort` and `*wPort` are null.
And then you dereference them, and it goes boom.

The function is probably supposed to (dynamically) create new objects and assign their addresses to `*ePort` and `*wPort`.

It's not obvious what type of objects to create, but I would expect it to look something like this (but with some error handling):

```
int check_inband_status(Port **ePort, Port **wPort, InbandPort *inbandPort)
{
    std::ifstream ring_config_file(RING_CONFIG_FILE);
    Json::Value ring_config;
    ring_config_file >> ring_config;
    Port* east = new Port;
    east->port_id = ring_config["east_port"]["port_id"].asInt();
    east->port_type = ring_config["east_port"]["port_type"].asString();
    Port* west = new Port;
    west->port_id = ring_config["west_port"]["port_id"].asInt();
    west->port_type = ring_config["west_port"]["port_type"].asString();
    *ePort = east;
    *wPort = west;
    return something_meaningful;
}
```

Another option is that it's *not* supposed to create objects dynamically but just modify them.
In that case, you need just one level of pointer (or a reference):

```
int check_inband_status(Port *east, Port *west, InbandPort *inbandPort)
{
    std::ifstream ring_config_file(RING_CONFIG_FILE);
    Json::Value ring_config;
    ring_config_file >> ring_config;
    east->port_id = ring_config["east_port"]["port_id"].asInt();
    east->port_type = ring_config["east_port"]["port_type"].asString();
    west->port_id = ring_config["west_port"]["port_id"].asInt();
    west->port_type = ring_config["west_port"]["port_type"].asString();
    return something_meaningful;
}

// ...

Port ePort;
Port wPort;
check_inband_status(&ePort, &wPort, inbandPort);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a typical C interface for a setup or init function to me.

Double pointers (`object_type**`) is used so the object can be allocated on the heap and the address can be returned to the caller of the function. And I fear, that's what you are missing. You try to write to an object, that doesn't exist.

If the caller of the function was benign, they initialized the pointer to `nullptr` before passing it (or let's better say, its address) to the function and you can verify, that it has to be created first. But since `nullptr` initialization is not default, you cannot count on it.

Just a few days ago, CppCon channel on YouTube posted a nice talk of last years event on the basics of pointers (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zd8eznWv4k).